# Windows Security dialog looses focus and becomes unclickable in WPF app

Tags: wpf, windows-security

Some users of our application need to be able to connect using a proxy. The first time that the app makes a request requiring proxy authentication, the request fails with the 407 error code, as expected, and Windows pops a dialog like the following...

[image: Popup dialog]

That's all well and good, but the dialog looses focus and becomes unclickable with no way for the user to bring it back into focus.

Is there a way to either override this dialog with a WPF dialog that interacts better with the application, or ensure that this dialog keeps focus?

Edit:
This question: [Windows Security dialog owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785820/setting-the-windows-security-dialog-owner-during-a-client-certificate-involvin) seems to be similar, but not identical.

Comment: can you show your code? :)

Comment: It's a multi-million line enterprise application. I could probably spend a while to create a minimal reproducible scenario, but I'm not sure that's helpful since it's not our code that even shows this dialog as it's a Windows dialog that shows up when your internet proxy is not authenticated.